# How to query multiple Django models describing denormalized tables

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I'm trying to extract information from a number of denormalized tables, using Django models. The tables are pre-existing, part of a legacy MySQL database.

#### Schema description

Let's say that each table describes traits about a person, and each person has a name (this essentially identifies the person, but does not correspond to some unifying "Person" table). For example:

```py
class JobInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='name')
    startdate = models.DateField(db_column='startdate')
    ...

class Hobbies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='name')
    exercise = models.CharField(db_column='exercise')
    ...

class Clothing(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, db_column='name')
    shoes = models.CharField(db_column='shoes')
    ...

# Twenty more classes exist, all of the same format
```

#### Accessing via SQL

In raw SQL, when I want to access information across all tables, I do a series of ugly `OUTER JOIN`s, refining it with a `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT JobInfo.startdate, JobInfo.employer, JobInfo.salary,
       Hobbies.exercise, Hobbies.fun,
       Clothing.shoes, Clothing.shirt, Clothing,pants
       ...
FROM JobInfo
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Hobbies ON Hobbies.name = JobInfo.name
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Clothing ON Clothing.name = JobInfo.name
     ...
WHERE
     Clothing.shoes REXEGP "Nike" AND
     Hobbies.exercise REGEXP "out"
     ...;
```

#### Model-based approach

I'm trying to convert this to a Django-based approach, where I can easily get a `QuerySet` that pulls in information from all tables.

I've looked into using a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) ([example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/)), making one table have a field for tying it to each of the others. However, this would mean that one table needs the "central" table, which all others reference in reverse. This seems like a mess with twenty-odd fields, and doesn't really make schematic sense (is "job info" the core properties? clothes?).

I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way. How should I be building a `QuerySet` on related tables, where each table has one primary key field common across all tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DB access allows this, I would probably do this by defining a `Person` model, then declare the `name` DB column to be a foreign key to that model with `to_field` set as the name on the person model.  Then you can use the usual `__` syntax in your queries.

Assuming Django doesn't complain about a `ForeignKey` field with `primary_key=True`, anyway.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=...)

class JobInfo(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, primary_key=True, db_column='name', to_field='name')
    startdate = models.DateField(db_column='startdate')
    ...
```

I don't think `to_field` is actually required as long as `name` is declared as your primary key, but I think it's good for clarity.  Or if you don't declare `name` as the PK on person.

I haven't tested this, though.

To use a view, you have two options.  I think both would do best with an actual table containing all the known user names, maybe with a numeric PK as Django usually expects as well.  Let's assume that table exists - call it `person`.

One option is to create a single large view to encompass all information about a user, similar to the big join you use above - something like:

```
create or replace view person_info as 
    select person.id, person.name,
           jobinfo.startdate, jobinfo.employer, jobinfo.salary,
           hobbies.exercise, hobbies.fun,
           clothing.shoes, ...
    from person
         left outer join hobbies on hobbies.name = person.name
         left outer join jobinfo on jobinfo.name = person.name
         left outer join clothing on clothing.name = person.name
;
```

That might take a little debugging, but the idea should be clear.

Then declare your model with `db_table = person_info` and `managed = False` in the `Meta class`.

A second option would be to declare a view for each subsidiary table that includes the `person_id` value matching the name, then just use Django FKs.

```
create or replace view jobinfo_by_person as
    select person.id as person_id, jobinfo.*
    from person inner join jobinfo on jobinfo.name = person.name;
create or replace view hobbies_by_person as
    select person.id as person_id, hobbies.*
    from person inner join hobbies on hobbies.name = person.name;
```

etc.  Again, I'm not totally sure the .* syntax will work - if not, you'd have to list all the fields you're interested in.  And check what the column names from the subsidiary tables are.

Then point your models at the `by_person` versions and use the standard FK setup.

This is a little inelegant and I make no claims for good performance, but it does let you avoid further denormalizing your database.

Comment: I should mention I have root access to the database, I'm just trying to preserve the existing schema as much as possible. I'll give this a try, thanks.

Comment: Another option would be to create a view containing your joined data model and declare that as an unmanaged model.  But I think the foreign key approach is better, if it works.

Comment: Hm. It doesn't seem Django allows strings to act as a `ForeignKey`. When accessing `person` on a `JobInfo` object, I get: `invalid literal for int() with base 10`.

Comment: I am not wholly surprised but that is disappointing.  A view would probably do it, as long as you just need to read information out and not write back.  You could probably write your own model field class to act like a `ForeignKey`, but that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I only need read access, so the view seems a superior approach. However, I'm not quite sure how I'd go about creating such a view. Might you be able to point me to some documentation?

Comment: I've put some thoughts into my answer.  I have to google the view syntax every time I want to create one - mysql docs are here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Comment: Sorry for the very late acceptance- I wanted to test your suggestions first, but forgot to get back to you. Anyway, I ended up taking the "master model" approach, modifying my schema such that one model has a `OneToOneField` mapping to each relevant model.